Why does $L_1$ weight decay negatively impact adversarial training for logistic regression?
I am reading through the original paper on the Fast Gradient Sign Method (Explaining and Harnessing Adversarial Examples by Ian Goodfellow et. al).
We define an adversarial example as:
$$\tilde{x}=x+\eta$$
where $\eta=\epsilon\text{sign}\nabla_x(J(\theta,x,y)$
Substituting the adversarial example into the objective function, our new goal becomes to minimize (wrt to $w$):
$$\zeta(y(\epsilon||w||_1-w^Tx-b))$$
where $\zeta$ is the softplus function $\log(1+\exp(z))$
The paper goes on to say:

Most
significantly, the $L_1$ penalty is subtracted off the model’s activation during training, rather than
added to the training cost. This means that the penalty can eventually start to disappear if the model
learns to make confident enough predictions that ζ saturates. This is not guaranteed to happen—in
the underfitting regime, adversarial training will simply worsen underfitting. We can thus view $L_1$
weight decay as being more “worst case” than adversarial training, because it fails to deactivate in
the case of good margin.

I have the following questions:

If the penalty starts to disappear as the model is more and more confident, is this not equivalent to the weight decay "deactivating" in the case of a good margin? What would "deactivating" in this context mean?

The paper seems to imply that the weight decay baked in from the adversarial example seems to negatively impact adversarial training. However, the paper earlier on states that:



The adversarial perturbation causes the activation to grow by $w^T\eta$. We can maximize this increase
subject to the max norm constraint on η by assigning η = sign($w$). If $w$ has $n$ dimensions and the
average magnitude of an element of the weight vector is $m$, then the activation will grow by $\epsilon mn$.

So wouldn't weight decay reduce $m$ and thus reduce the impact of the adversarial example on the activation function? Is this not a good thing? Why, then, does $L_1$ weight decay negatively impact adversarial training?
